# How to pass NPM custom args on Windows 10?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to install a NPM package with special option which is:

```
PUPPETEER_PRODUCT=firefox npm install puppeteer
```

It works well on Linux , but when doing it on windows I get the next error

```
PUPPETEER_PRODUCT=firefox : The term 'PUPPETEER_PRODUCT=firefox' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
```

Can anybody help me to get it working on Windows 10 please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything works. Try it this way:

```
    npm init
    PUPPETEER_PRODUCT=firefox npm install puppeteer@5.0.0
```

And also

> This is an important step and the one you might run into issues in
> case you are working on an existing project. Delete node_modules
> directory if it already exists as the Firefox build is not downloaded
> if the puppeteer package already exists in node_modules.

Maybe it will help

Comment: Opened empty folder and did the steps ,still not working

Comment: I'm executing it through the terminal of visual code and it says its "powershell" , how do you execute it

Comment: Yes, to be honest, I'm not sure about the fact that npm can be used in Visual Code at all (can you?). It's just that whenever I need to install something additionally, I use Git Bash.